# Getting extents of raster with GeoTransform

Tags: python, raster, gdal, extents, affine-transformation

I'm trying to better understand GeoTransform. For getting the extents of a raster, I've seen solutions posted such as below. But doesn't this only account for perfectly square rasters? From my understanding it gets the upper left x and y geographical positions, gets the geographical distance covered by an individual pixel, and the amount of pixels.

```
import gdal
from gdalconst import GA_ReadOnly

data = gdal.Open('C:/Temp/myimage.tif', GA_ReadOnly)
geoTransform = data.GetGeoTransform()
minx = geoTransform[0]
maxy = geoTransform[3]
maxx = minx + geoTransform[1] * data.RasterXSize
miny = maxy + geoTransform[5] * data.RasterYSize
print [minx, miny, maxx, maxy]
data = None

upper_left = [minx, maxy]
bottom_left = [minx, miny]
upper_right = [maxx, maxy]
bottom_right = [maxx, miny]
```

If you were attempting to redraw the shape with this, it would only work for perfect squares right? If the lower left corner is shifted slightly further left from the top left, it wouldn't be accounted for?

When I do gdalinfo, I get the following results for corner coordinates:

Corner Coordinates:

Upper Left  (  248061.434, 4620818.949) ( 72d 1'39.76"W, 41d41'57.41"N)

Lower Left  (  248061.434, 4553370.949) ( 71d59'58.78"W, 41d 5'33.28"N)

Upper Right (  275337.434, 4620818.949) ( 71d42' 1.04"W, 41d42'26.81"N)

Lower Right (  275337.434, 4553370.949) ( 71d40'30.95"W, 41d 6' 2.06"N)

Center      (  261699.434, 4587094.949) ( 71d51' 2.32"W, 41d24' 0.34"N)

Comment: Rasters are always perfect rectangles with some fixed number of rows and columns. Some of the pixels may present nodata. If you are interested in the area covered by of valid pixels in different projections I think that you should polygonize the valid area and use the vectorized version for further analysis.

Comment: Oh, so thats why there's also a "ghost" pixel with no data around some parts of my raster. Its padding that extra pixel to create a perfect rectangle. That makes sense. Thanks. I edited in gdalinfo results. Do you know why the coordinates in the results appear to be the same in meters but different in degrees? The meter results make sense to me if its a perfect rectangle.

Comment: What is the coordinate system of your data?

Comment: EPSG:32619 - WGS 84 / UTM zone 19N - Projected

Comment: Corner coordinates are expressed in two different coordinate systems. What is rectangular in one does not need to be that in another. Actually the lon-lat coordinates are achieved by converting the corner points in the vector world. You can try and convert coordinates corner by corner. `gdaltransform -s_srs epsg:32619 -t_srs epsg:4326
Enter X Y [Z [T]] values separated by space, and press Return.
248061.434 4620818.949
-72.0277103882385 41.6992808880501 0
248061.434 4553370.949
-71.9996603133268 41.0925770822793 0`.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. I tried flipping the conversion and it looks like there's such a small difference in meters it gets lost during rounding. So when I calculate corners in the code with GeoTransform, the numbers are actually going to be the same no matter what since I'm explicitly equating the top left x coord to the bottom left x coord without accounting for coordinate system. gdalinfo is showing us the corner coords while taking into account the coord system. Errors could happen through that. So polygonizing like you mentioned might be better instead of finding boundaries this way.